# QT анимация цвета

Tags: qt, анимация, color

Здравствуйте, необходимо сделать анимацию цвета кнопки, чтобы цвет постепенно менялся с одного на другой. Нашел лишь пример анимации перемещения:

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(myWidget, "geometry");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));
animation->start();
```

Пытался изменить под цвет, но это ни к чему не привело. Хелп!

Comment: Попробуйте так:
`animation->setStartValue("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100)");
animation->setEndValue("background-color: rgb(250, 250, 100)");
animation->setDuration(10000);

animation->start();`
Работает не всегда.

Comment: QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->generate);
    animation->setStartValue("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 100)");
    animation->setEndValue("background-color: rgb(250, 250, 100)");
    animation->setDuration(10000);
    animation->start();

Comment: в консоли следующее сообщение: QPropertyAnimation::updateState (): Changing state of an animation without target

Comment: а если немного погуглить? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445507/change-background-color-of-qwidget-using-animation